# Couldn't find executable named Keyboard below /home/robot-raspi/catkin_ws/src/mobile_robot_pkg

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the book Robot Operating System ROS For Absolute Begginers.
I am trying to make the book robot but I have an error using the command:

```
rosrun mobile_robot_pkg Keyboard robot_bt_driver.py
```

Error:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named Keyboard below / home / pablo-rdgz / catkin_ws / src / mobile_robot_pkg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330815/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-keyboard-below-/home/robot-raspi/catkin_ws/src/mobile_robot_pkg/) by [PabloRC](https://answers.ros.org/users/44863/pablorc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-08-15**:
Can you please make your question readable by removing the boilerplate comments from your CMakeLists.txt file and using *preformatted text* (`101010`) button. Also, some more context is probably going to be needed as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The syntax for `rosrun` is

```
rosrun <package-name> <executable>
```

It looks like, in your case, `<package-name>` is `mobile_robot_pkg` and `<executable>` is `robot_bt_driver.py`. So, the command should be

```
rosrun mobile_robot_pkg robot_bt_driver.py
```

I'm not sure what `Keyboard` is.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-08-15**:
Also, make sure that your node is executable by running

```
chmod +x robot_bt_driver.py
```

**Comment by [PabloRC](https://answers.ros.org/users/44863/pablorc/) on 2019-08-15**:
chmod: cannot access 'robot_bt_driver.py': No such file or directory

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-08-15**:
You have to run that command from the directory in which that file is located

**Comment by [PabloRC](https://answers.ros.org/users/44863/pablorc/) on 2019-08-15**:
thank you very much it finally works

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-08-15**:
Great. Can you please mark this answer as correct by clicking on the check mark?